# How to use variables from the creator in an asynchronously called lambda in elisp?

Tags: asynchronous, lambda, elisp

I am trying to call a function as a [Sentinel](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sentinels.html#), but it needs some additional information, besides the process and the event. My idea was to use a lambda, which adds the additional arguments like this:

```lisp
(set-process-sentinel proc
                      (lambda (proc event)
                        (my-sentinel buffer remaining proc event)))
```

But this fails, with a `Symbol’s value as variable is void`. As this happens inside a function and the additional data is defined as parameter/using `let`, I assume, that the function, which is setting the sentinel, finishes and the variables are deleted before the sentinel is called. To test this I used the following:

```lisp
(let* ((fmt-string "Hello, %s!")
       (func (lambda (name)
               (message fmt-string name))))
  (funcall func "world"))

(let* ((fmt-string "Hello, %s!")
       (func (lambda (name)
               (message fmt-string name))))
  (run-at-time "1 sec" nil func "world"))
```

The first test runs successfully, and the second one fails with a `Symbol’s value as variable is void`, which seems to confirm my hypothesis.

How else can I pass additional information to the Sentinel? Using `setq` is not an option, as there may be multiple sentinels requiring different values at the same time.

For a bit of context: I am trying to execute multiple, asynchronous subprocesses using `start-process`, which have to be run in order. The Sentinel is used to start the next process once the current finishes (`buffer` is used for output, `remaining` holds information about the subprocesses to be started). A different way to archive this would also solve my problem.

Comment: You can [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote) your lambda form in order to *unquote* (using a comma) the values you wish to be evaluated while they are still in scope.  You can also enable [lexical binding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lexical-Binding.html) for your library, in which case you can create *closures* instead of using backquoting.  Or without lexical binding you could still use the old `lexical-let` macro from `cl.el`.

Comment: n.b. As well as the marked duplicate itself, some of the comments on that Q&A link to other useful explanations.